# Unable to load sample data into ldap Server with the help of ldif file

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I need to insert bulk data into the LDAP server for this I used  LdapTestUtils 
class but got some error

Gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-ldap'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.ldap', name: 'spring-ldap-test', version: '2.3.2.RELEASE'
}
```

Java code

```
public static void loadData() throws Exception
    {
        // Bind to the directory
        LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        contextSource.setUrl("ldap://127.0.0.1:10389");
        contextSource.setUserDn("uid=admin,ou=system");
        contextSource.setPassword("secret");
        contextSource.setPooled(false);
        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        // Create the Sprint LDAP template
        LdapTemplate template = new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
        // Clear out any old data - and load the test data
        LdapTestUtils.clearSubContexts(contextSource, LdapUtils.newLdapName("dc=example,dc=com"));
        LdapTestUtils.loadLdif(contextSource, new ClassPathResource("schema.ldif"));
    }
```

Link  - https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.ldap.test.LdapTestUtils
first example

Error - org.apcahe.directory.server.core can not be resolve it is indirectly referred from require.class file

What dependency am i missing?
Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: can you please post the full error log.

Comment: The same compile time error as i am showing

Comment: @UDITJOSHI where do you get the dependency for LdapTestUtils?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void loadData() throws Exception
    {
        // Bind to the directory
        LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        contextSource.setUrl("ldap://127.0.0.1:10389");
        contextSource.setUserDn("uid=admin,ou=system");
        contextSource.setPassword("secret");
        contextSource.setPooled(false);
        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        // Create the Sprint LDAP template
        LdapTemplate template = new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
        // Clear out any old data - and load the test data
     LdapTestUtils.cleanAndSetup(
                contextSource,
                LdapUtils.newLdapName("dn to remove"),
                new ClassPathResource("schema.ldif"));

          }
```

cleanAndSetup method works for me but it will restart server as well